# How to refresh graphics of a Window class in Java

Tags: java, awt, vlcj

I'm trying to draw over a vlcj (java binding of the VLC library) panel so that I can play a video and draw over it. And I have encounter some issues. Here is the full base code:

**Code-listing 1: AppOverlay.java**

```
package app;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import com.sun.jna.platform.WindowUtils;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class AppOverlay extends Window implements Runnable {

    private final boolean isRunning;
    private final int fps;
    private BufferedImage graphics;
    private BufferedImage img;
    private int x, y;
    private boolean ltr;

    public AppOverlay(Window owner) {
        super(owner, WindowUtils.getAlphaCompatibleGraphicsConfiguration());
        setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));

        graphics    = new BufferedImage(1280,800, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        isRunning   = true;
        img         = null;
        ltr         = true;
        fps         = 60;
        x           = 0;
        y           = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(isRunning){

            try{
                Thread.sleep(1000/fps);
            } catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(ltr) {
                if(x < 1280) x++;
                else ltr = false;
            } else {
                if(x < 0) ltr = true;
                else x--;
            }

            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void createAndShowGUI() {
        setVisible(true);

        Thread thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();

        String path = "Drive:\\path\\to\\image.png";
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new java.io.FileInputStream(path));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        Graphics2D gfx = graphics.createGraphics();
        gfx.setColor(new Color(255,255,255,0));
        gfx.clearRect(0, 0, 1280, 800);
        if(img != null) gfx.drawImage(img, x, y, null);
        gfx.dispose();
        g2d.drawImage(graphics, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

**Code-listing 2: AppPlayer.java**

```
package app;

import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.component.EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class AppPlayer extends EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent {

}
```

**Code-listing 3: AppFrame.java**

```
package app;

import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class AppFrame extends JFrame {

    private AppPlayer appPlayer;
    private AppOverlay overlay;

    public AppFrame(){
        super();
    }

    public void createAndShowGUI() {

        appPlayer = new AppPlayer();
        appPlayer.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1280,800));
        getContentPane().add(appPlayer);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("App");
        setVisible(true);
        pack();

        overlay = new AppOverlay(this);
        appPlayer.mediaPlayer().overlay().set(overlay);
        appPlayer.mediaPlayer().overlay().enable(true);
        overlay.createAndShowGUI();
    }
}
```

**Code-listing 4: Main.java**

```
package main;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import app.AppFrame;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final AppFrame app = new AppFrame();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                app.createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

with that and the vlcj-4 library you should be able to test my code yourself. My issue is that the Overlay (AppOverlay class that extends the Window class) doesn't display or refresh the animation unless I deselect the window (I click on another window or on the desktop or the OS toolbar) so that the window (application) is inactive then select the window (the application) again. It will only load one frame and that's it. I have to deselect and reselect the window again for it to load another frame (this is only the case for the Overlay i.e. if I play a video in the AppPlayer class the video will be playing just fine.

What I want is to be able to draw some animated graphics on the overlay. I know that with the JPanel class there is the paintComponent() method but the Window class doesn't have that method (only the paint() and repaint() methods are available).

What should I do to fix this?

**EDIT:**

I tried adding a JPanel on which I draw instead of drawing directly on the AppOverlay

**Code-listing 5: AppPanel.java**

```
package app;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class AppPanel extends JPanel implements Runnable {
    private int x, y;
    private boolean ltr;

    public AppPanel() {
        x   = 0;
        y   = 0;
        ltr = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(new Color(0,0,0,0));
        g.clearRect(0, 0, 1280, 800);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 100, 100);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){

            try{
                Thread.sleep(1000/60);
            } catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(ltr) {
                if(x < 1280) x++;
                else ltr = false;
            } else {
                if(x < 0) ltr = true;
                else x--;
            }

            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

then adding it to the AppOverlay.

**Code-listing 6: AppOverlay.java** with partial modification

```
public class AppOverlay extends Window implements Runnable {
    //previous field declaration above ...
    AppPanel panel;
    AppPlayer player = null;

    public AppOverlay(Window owner) {
        //previous constructor instructions above...

        panel = new AppPanel();
        add(panel);
    }

    public void createAndShowGUI(AppPlayer player) {
        setVisible(true);

        /*
        Thread thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();

        String path = "Drive:\\path\\to\\image.png";
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new java.io.FileInputStream(path));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        */

        Thread panelThread = new Thread(panel);
        panelThread.start();
    }
}
```

Doing this will display the graphics of the JPanel and animate them as needed.

If you know a way to make the JPanel background transparent (so that we can see through it) while still letting it display its graphics. That would solve the issue for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played around a bit with your example and came up with something working, but I wouldn't call it a nice solution.

The main issue seems to be that there is no way to tell the overlay to refresh (or I just have not found it). Just `repainting` the overlay does not update it on screen, so the workaround I used is to hide and show it again.

For the timeing of the update interval I used a `javax.swing.Timer`.
(In a real version you probably want to start and stop the timer via the `MediaPlayerEventListener`).

As a side effect the `repaint` method is called and the `x` coordinate is adjusted to move the image around the screen.

In the simplified example below (use your `main` to run it), I moved a red rectangle with the x coordinate instead of some unknown image.

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Timer;

import com.sun.jna.platform.WindowUtils;

import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.component.EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.OverlayApi;

public class AppFrame extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1569823648323129877L;

    public class Overlay extends Window {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 8337750467830040964L;

        private int x, y;
        private boolean ltr = true;

        public Overlay(Window owner) throws HeadlessException {
            super(owner, WindowUtils.getAlphaCompatibleGraphicsConfiguration());
            setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {

            super.paint(g);

            if (ltr) {
                if (x < 1180)
                    x += 1;
                else
                    ltr = false;
            } else {
                if (x < 0)
                    ltr = true;
                else
                    x -= 1;
            }

            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillRect(x, y, 100, 100);

            String s = Integer.toString(x);
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.drawChars(s.toCharArray(), 0, s.length(), x+10, y+50);
        }
    }

    private EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent appPlayer;

    public void createAndShowGUI() {

        appPlayer = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();
        appPlayer.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1280, 800));
        getContentPane().add(appPlayer);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("App");
        setVisible(true);
        pack();

        Overlay overlay = new Overlay(this);

        OverlayApi api = appPlayer.mediaPlayer().overlay();
        api.set(overlay);
        api.enable(true);

        //appPlayer.mediaPlayer().media().play(" ... ");

        Timer timer = new Timer(0, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                api.enable(false);
                api.enable(true);
            }
        });
        timer.setRepeats(true);
        timer.setDelay(200);
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

---

If that is an option for you, it might be far easier to use an `animated gif` instead. At least that is working on its own (no need for the Timer).

---

**Update:**

As you figured out using a `JPanel` seems to work better. 
Just use `setOpaque(false)` to make it transparent.

Here an adjusted example.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.component.EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.OverlayApi;

public class AppFrame2 extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1569823648323129877L;

    public class OverlayPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 8070414617530302145L;

        private int x, y;
        private boolean ltr = true;

        public OverlayPanel() {
            this.setOpaque(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {

            super.paint(g);

            if (ltr) {
                if (x < 1180)
                    x += 1;
                else
                    ltr = false;
            } else {
                if (x < 0)
                    ltr = true;
                else
                    x -= 1;
            }

            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillRect(x, y, 100, 100);

            String s = Integer.toString(x);
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.drawChars(s.toCharArray(), 0, s.length(), x+10, y+50);
        }
    }

    public class Overlay extends Window {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 8337750467830040964L;

        OverlayPanel panel;

        public Overlay(Window owner) throws HeadlessException {
            super(owner);
            setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));

            panel = new OverlayPanel();
            this.add(panel);
        }
    }

    private EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent appPlayer;

    public void createAndShowGUI() {

        appPlayer = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();
        appPlayer.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1280, 800));
        getContentPane().add(appPlayer);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("App");
        setVisible(true);
        pack();

        Overlay overlay = new Overlay(this);

        OverlayApi api = appPlayer.mediaPlayer().overlay();
        api.set(overlay);
        api.enable(true);

        //appPlayer.mediaPlayer().media().play(" ... ");

        Timer timer = new Timer(0, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                overlay.panel.repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.setRepeats(true);
        timer.setDelay(17);
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: The root cause of the `repaint` not working seems to be the `non opaqueness` of the `awt window`. The [`docu`](http://capricasoftware.co.uk/projects/vlcj-4/tutorials/overlay) mentions some issues prior to Java 7 but sadly nothing for newer java versions.

Comment: I tried your code, with and without playing a video. This is clever but unfortunately the overlay is blinking. it seems switching back and forth from disable to enable makes it disappear for a short but noticeable time. I am also worried of what would happen if I add a MouseListener to the overlay and try to click on the area where the red box is (which is something I want to do as the project grows): there might be (short) times when I wouldn't be able to click on the red box because the overlay and therefore its MouseListener will be disabled.

Comment: I've edited my question because I found out that JPanel display the graphics smoothly.

Comment: I added another example that uses a `non opaque` JPanel. As you said this seems to be much smoother.

Comment: The example is better than the previous one. No more blinking. but for some reason the animation isn't smooth (maybe it's my computer even though the animation runs smoothly without vlcj). I will give you the bounty anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You have already done the bulk of the work. Simply repaint the frame every time you draw over it by calling `app.repaint();`

Comment: I tried calling the repaint method of the AppFrame class. I made the class Runnable and called the repaint method inside a while loop in the run method. Then I started the thread which is the same as calling app.repaint outside of the AppFrame class. It didn't work. You can try it yourself, you'll see!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following methods from JComponent: ( http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html )

```
void    repaint(long tm, int x, int y, int width, int height)
 //**Adds the specified region to the dirty region list if the component is showing.*//
void    repaint(Rectangle r)
 /**Adds the specified region to the dirty region list if the component is showing.*//
You can call those before redraw()
```

Comment: JComponent is a swing component not an awt component. Also `java.awt.Window` doesn't extend `javax.swing.JComponent` but `java.awt.Component`. So I tried every repaint methods of the java.awt.Component class (`void repaint()`, `void repaint(int x, int y, int width, int height)`, `void repaint(long tm)` and `void repaint(long tm, int x, int y, int width, int height)`) inside the run method of the AppOverlay. none of them worked. You can try my code with the JComponent yourself. You'll see it won't work (especially the `void repaint(Rectangle r)`.

Comment: The Window class is an awt component not a swing component. Also it is in no way extending JComponent. instead it extends java.awt.Component (just like the JComponent). So I tried every repaint methods from java.awt.Component (`void repaint`, joshua`void    repaint(long tm, int x, int y, int width, int height)`,